# Como criar um diretório em Java usando NIO.2 - Java SE 7

Tags: java, sistema-de-arquivos, diretório, io

A API **java.nio** é parte da plataforma Java SE desde sua versão 1.4. Agora, a partir do Java 7, passamos a ter diversos novos *enhancements* nesta API e novas funcionalidades, que fornecem um melhor gerenciamento do sistema de arquivos (*file system*) e oferecem vários métodos utilitários.

Como criamos ***um*** diretório usando tais recursos?

Como criamos ***diretórios*** usando tais recursos?

Quais são as particularidades da utilização destes métodos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe `java.nio.files.Files` traz consigo grande parte destas novas Funcionalidades e facilidades.

No caso da necessidade de criacão de um ou mais diretórios, vamos ver como os métodos estáticos `Files.createDirectory(Path)` e `Files.createDirectories(Path)` funcionam.

> Como criamos ***um*** diretório usando tais recursos?

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths
                .get("/home/user/Documents/directoryCreatedFromJavaApp2");
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Na classe acima, estamos utilizando primeiramente a classe `Path`, que representa o *path* - caminho - para o arquivo diretório que queremos criar. Obtemos uma instância dela a partir da chamada ao método de fabricação estático que está na classe `Paths`. Definimos através do método `Paths.get(String)` - através da `String` passada como parâmetro, qual é o diretório que desejamos criar.

**...`createDirectory(Path)` - no singular**

Exato, aqui reside um detalhe importante. Este método cria apenas um diretório, o último na nossa `String`: `/home/user/Documents/directoryCreatedFromJavaApp2`

Ou seja, criamos aqui o diretório `directoryCreatedFromJavaApp2`.

**Então os diretórios antes deste já deve existir?**

Exato, caso não existam, o método lançará `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` indicando a inexistência do caminho prévio, o que nos leva a ter de capturar `IOException` (também podemos apenas propagar a exceção dependendo de nosso design).

**E se o diretório que eu estiver criando já existir?**

Neste caso o método `Files.createDirectory(Path)` lançará uma exceção: `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException`, portanto a necessidade de continuarmos capturando `IOException` - superclasse de  `FileAlreadyExistsException`.

> Como criamos ***diretórios*** usando tais recursos?

Então agora, veremos o método `Files.createDirectories(Path)`.

Vejamos um exemplo:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths
                .get("/home/user/Documents/directory1/directory2/directory3");
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Novamente, notamos no código acima que tivemos que usar um objeto `Path`. Na verdade a única diferença foi no método para criação do diretório, no nosso caso, ...*directories* no plural. Agora um ponto importante, diferentemente do método anterior, este método não requer que os diretórios pais do último diretório existam, pois caso não existam, serão criados.

**E se o o diretório já existir ao chamarmos `Files.createDirectories(Path)`?**

Nenhuma exceção será lançada, na verdade, nada acontecerá com o diretório

Para mais detalhes consultar os Javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html